# How to make oracle apex 5.1 multi-language application

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to make multi-language application using oracle apex 5.1 step by step , and be able to switch between them in runtime
Thanks

Comment: You will need to [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/understanding-application-translation-and-globalization-support.htm#HTMDB14001) on that.

Comment: There's also a few books with chapters dedicated to the topic https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781849681346/6